# Where can I ask a question related to changing career?

Tags: discussion

I am wondering where I should ask a question related to changing career, specializing,  getting a career coach in the field of electronics engineering?
With certain age, place and if even it is possible?

Comment: You might as well ask it here, but I think it would require a lot more information like your age, your location, the time frame you have in mind, your current job (if any), your education level, and your reason for choosing electronics engineering (and not something else). Please note that you can just [edit] your question instead of starting a new one. Also, I think the answer is "yes" and I strongly recommend you avoid asking a "yes" or "no" question on here. We hate those types of questions. Instead, you should ask for ways to improve your chances in your endeavor.

Comment: I am preparing my most important points to include here

Answer (score 1):

As well as asking a question on The Workplace, for a specific field (eg electronics engineering) you could find one or several relevant stacks in the network (like say https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) find their main chat room (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering), and ask the regulars in there if they can offer you some advice.

Answer (score -1):

Nah this suite isn't the place for that at all.

Try quora, you uf you must online.

Your university will have careers coaches, and those coaches will also know OF careers coaches to help  at your level.

Finally, all ppl need a mentor, so go find one.